# Question in proof of Dummit Foote abstract algebra 6.1 theorem 3

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I'm confused about the part that $2)$ implies $3)$. I can see that by Sylow theorem, we have $$\begin{align*}
P \text{ char } N \lhd   N_{G}(N)
\end{align*}$$ where $N=N_{G}(P)$ and $N_{G}(N)=N_{G}(N_{G}(P))$ which is the normalizer of $P$ 's normalizer.  Then $P$ is characteristic in $N$ and $N$ is normal in $N_{G}(N)$, and I can understand this implies $P \lhd N_{G}(N)$.However, I can't see why this implies $$\begin{align*}
N_{G}(N) < N
\end{align*}$$ Can somebody explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P\trianglelefteq N_G(N)$ means that for any $g\in N_G(N)$ we have $gPg^{-1}=P$. But this by definition tells us that any such $g$ belongs to $N_G(P)=N$.